# How can I set profiles with spring boot and maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have 2 environments to set my API, so i have production and dev. My need first of all was find a way to do this automatically, for example, in runtime without sent any parameter (-D) the application found a way to identify the environemnt who it are, but i didn't find any method to do this way.

So I read a tutorial, in the same have a way to put a environment variable, and define my application.properties. So in the follow steps:

1. I define 3 files in my application, application.properties, application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties.
2. Inside the application.properties I have the configuration spring.profiles.active=${MYENV:local}.
3. Inside the application-dev.properties I have spring.profiles.active=dev.
4. Inside the application-prod.properties I have spring.profiles.active=prod.
5. I know if i pass the command mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=(PROFILE) the Spring select the profile perfectly.

I have two questions:

1. My environment variable is correctly on the Windows, why when I run my application the spring don't populate the variable on the ${MYENV:local}, Do I need to do any more configuration?
2. I'm starting to work with microservices, so if i have several microservices this way to set environment variables will be hard to maintain. Is there any way more easy to configure profiles without to send command line?

Answer (score 3):

In the following different ways you can set the profiles:

1) Using application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

2) Using @Profile annotation:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ "profile1", "profile2" })
public class Test {

  @Bean
  public Employee employee() {
    ...
  }
}
```

3) Using maven:

```
<profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <activeProfile>production</activeProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

4) Using vmargument we can do it like as below:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=production"
```

5) Using System.setProperty():

```
System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
```

6) By implementing WebApplicationInitializer

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    }
}
```

7) Using web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass variable `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` to the vm during your application launch.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Do not put this variable into your `application-${env}.properties` file. The whole point is that spring resolves proper config during application start based on `spring.profiles.active`. So in your case you dont need `application.properties` file. You can simply remove that. Leave your dev and prod config and supply a proper variable. You do not set it within your system variables - you need to instruct your app directly. Try:

`java -jar myApplication.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

If you want your env be resolved based on system property you can try:

`java -jar myApplication.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=%MYENV%`

If you want to know which env app is running, you can try:

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String activeProfile;
```

Maven profiles are resolved during compilation time. Those are two different worlds.

Comment: Hi sebastian, thanks to answer the question, i know the form to put the variable in the command line, but this way don't attend me. Thinks in the situation who I have 10 developers work in my application, every day their will need to remember to iniciate the local dev with command. Imagine the situation with any dev pass the command to run production in local machine for mistake and do something wrong. This alternative isnt safe for me.

Comment: So you can leave 2 files - `application.properties` - which would be picked up as a default without any variable passed and `application-prod.properties` which would be resolved on your production environment. Stay away from overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. What I personally find the most straight-forward is as follows :

Step 1 : In addition to your `application.properties` file, create more `property` files(one for each profile). For example - `application-test.properties` and `application-prod.properties`. Now you have three property files in your `resource` folder.

Step 2 : In your `application.properties` file, mention the current profile in  `spring.profiles.active`. For example - `spring.profiles.active=test` will activate test profile.

Step 3 : Define profile-specific beans.

```
@Bean
@Profile("test")
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {
        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames)
            System.out.println(beanName);
    };
}
```

This will create a bean iff one of the active profiles is `test`.